# Why do type constructors automatically yield parametrised construction?

Tags: logic, category-theory, type-theory

It does often seem to be the case that the unparametrised version of a concept  in category theory is not as useful as the parametrised version. This is especially the case when categories are discussed in relation to logic and type theory. For the rest of my question fix a category $\mathbb C$ with finite products (including a terminal object). Here are examples:

- A naive definition of a natural number object in $\mathbb C$ is: A natural number object is an initial diagram of shape $1\xrightarrow{0} N \xrightarrow{S}N$. But naive nnos seem not to be of much use if $\mathbb C$ is not cartesian closed. The standard definition of a natural number object is that of a parametrized natural number object (see the [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/natural+numbers+object) definition 2.2). Actually, calling them parametrized natural number objects is a bit misleading, since they are more properly called natural number objects with simple parameters. It is shown in Bart Jacob's book *Categorical Logic and Type Theory* that a naive natural number object is a natural number object with (simple) parameters if and only if it is preserved by each functor $I^*: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C//I$ into the simple slice category. The functor $I^*$ takes $X$ to the constant family $I\times X \to I$. The simple slice category is the full subcategory of $\mathbb C/I$ consisting of all constant families $I\times X \to I$.
- Coproducts can also be parametrized in a similar spirit. If the category $\mathbb C$ has binary coproducts, then it is distributive iff the canonical map $I\times A + I \times B \to I \times (A + B)$ is always an isomorphism. This is equivalent to saying that all the functors $I^*: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C//I$ preserve coproducts (proposition 2.6.1. in Jacobs book). Coproducts in a cartesian closed category are automatically distributive.
- Exponential objects themselves seem to have simple parameters. Let us say that a naive function space of $Y$ into $X$ in $\mathbb C$ is an object $X^Y$ such that morphisms $1 \to X^Y$ are in natural one to one correspondence with morphisms $Y \to X$. Now if each $I^*: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C//I$ preserves naive function spaces, then we can compute that
  \begin{align*}
  \mathbb C(I\times X, Y) &= (\mathbb C//I)(I^*X,I^*Y) = (\mathbb C//I)(1, I^*(X^Y)) \\&= (\mathbb C//I)(I^*1, I^*(X^Y)) = \mathbb C(I\times 1,X^Y) \\&= \mathbb C(I,X^Y)
  \end{align*}
  naturally, so that $X^Y$ is an exponential object in the usual sense. We did use that $I^*$ preserves terminal objects, and that $\mathbb C(I\times X,Z) = (\mathbb C//I)(I^*X,I^*Z)$ naturally. This also works in the other direction, so that again a naive function space is an actual exponential object if and only if it is preserved by all the functors $I^*$.
- Finite products come automatically with simple parameters.
- All the logical connectives in a first order hyperdoctrine seem to be defined with simple parameters in mind. For example a naive way to define equality for a hyperdoctrine (a pseudofunctor) $P: \mathbb C^{op} \to \mathbf{Cat}$ might be to ask for left adjoints of each of the substitution functors $\delta^*$ along diagonals $\delta: J \to J\times J$. But how equality is actually defined is as a left adjoint to substitution along parametrised diagonals $I\times \delta: I\times J \to I\times J \times J$. Similar for all the other logical connectives in between the fibres.

I have a vague sense, that we need constructors with simple parameters so that we can interpret the corresponding elimination and introduction rules also in non-empty contexts. Why are simple parameters so important, and why are categorical concepts without them 'useless'? Does it have something to do with the fact that a more natural setting to compare type theories and categories are multicategories (according to [Mike Shulman](https://mikeshulman.github.io/catlog/catlog.pdf))? Do the multicategorical versions of coproducts and natural number objects automatically come with simple parameters?

If we are to extend the interpretation of simple type theory in categories to dependent type theory, do we then need naive coproducts/nno etc. which are preserved by all slice functors $I^*: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C/I$ into the actual slice category?

Comment: It's a little unclear what sense of "why" you're using, here. For instance, parameterized NNO's are more useful insofar as we care about multi-variable primitive recursive functions–is that concrete kind of thing clear to you, and you're asking "why" in a deeper sense?

Comment: @Kevin Arlin Yes. I want to know why they pop up all over the place (in my categorical logic book). I have the feeling that non parametrised stuff is not only less usefull, it seems to be completely unusable in connection to type theory.

Comment: All the type constructors in type theory are automatically parametrised when translated into the language of categories

Comment: So a better question is perhabs why type constructors automatically parametrised

Comment: I am especially interested in if the same constructions in multicategories are automaticaly parametrised, as they seem to be in type theory.

Comment: Parametricity in the sense you ask about is forced by the structural weakening rules, no? If $\Gamma \vdash \Delta$ then also $A, \Gamma \vdash \Delta$ etc.

Comment: @ZhenLin yes, i guess. probably because N works as a natural number object even when we carry a fixed non-empty context around all the time,

Comment: @ZhenLin do you no if coproducts and natural number objects in multicategories have this property (or sth equivalent) by default?

Comment: I don't know what the standard definitions in multicategories are.